# link to last post - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to `link_to` the `show` action for a `post`.

In my `controller` I have:

```
@post = Post.all
```

In my view I'm trying to link it to the last post like this:

```
<%= link_to @post.last do %>
 <%= @post.last.title %>
<% end %>
```

But it does not take me to the show page for that post?

Comment: What do you mean by *it does not take me to the show page*? Where does it take you instead? Does it show an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Post.all` loads all posts, but does not guarantee an order. You might want to use the `id` or the `created_at` value to order your list of posts:

```
# in your controller
@posts = Post.order(:id)

# in the view:
<%= link_to @posts.last.title, @posts.last %>
```

Or - if you don't need the other posts in the view - just load the lastest post:

```
# in the controller:
@latest_post = Post.order(:id).last

# in the view:
<%= link_to @latest_post.title, @latest_post %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code,

```
<%= link_to post_path(@post.last) do %>
 <%= @post.last.title %>
<% end %>
```

If this code not work then please find route with fire `rake routes` in your terminal and replace `post_path` with your routes

Hope this will work.